# Run Process in background and ensure whether all got processed

Tags: bash, shell, unix, process

im trying to read the file line by line and call a subProcess that executes based in the parameter i pass.
The process we call has been designed to run in **Parallel**. So we plan to send all the lines of the File to the subprocess and run it in a background.
Is there an option to make my calling process wait or get to know whether all the background Process has been successfully Processed?

This is how i call that subprocess using the ShellScripting.

```
while read -r name age empno ; do
    echo $EmpName $EmpAge $EmpNumber
    ./run.sh RUN_EMP -a $EmpName -b $EmpAge -c $EmpNumber &  
    result=$?
done < "$File_Employee" >  /logs/Emp_`date +%Y%m%d%H%M`.log
```

Comment: The statement `result=$?` is in a peculiar position.  For which process are you trying to capture an exit code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have not started any other processes in your bash script (before the loop) the simplest way to wait for all your background jobs to terminate is simply to add

```
wait
```

after the loop. See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html.